# Wrong build variant

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.2

I have 2 modules in my app, one for the API, one for the app.
In the API module I define 2 API endpoint depending if the API is compiled in `debug` or `release` mode:

```
buildTypes {
    all {
        buildConfigField "String", "API_DEVICE_TYPE", "\"android-phone\""
    }

    debug {
        buildConfigField "String", "API_ENDPOINT", "\"https://beta-api.company.com/\""
    }

    release {
        buildConfigField "String", "API_ENDPOINT", "\"https://api.company.com/\""
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

In Android Studio's `Build variant` panel I selected the debug variant for both app and API module. But when I press play/clean/rebuild/remove all build directory by hand/resync gradle, well whatever I do this is the release API which get compiled every time.

Any hint?

Tried with gradle build tools `2.1.0` and `2.2.0-aplha3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this code in your submodule build.gradle

```
// There is a limitation in gradle: You can't pick what submodule of app you want to compile your app with.
// This attribut define which build variant you want your api to be compiled against.
// https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Library-Publication
defaultPublishConfig "debug"
```